# Bundle bundle = getArguments() returns null with no reason

Tags: java, android

i'm just facing a problem leading me craziness , I just want to pass a value between lists , when I click on an item in the list i want to send the `position` to another list ,so I used bundle and it worked for me ,but when  i improved my app to use `ViewPager` and `TabsPagerAdapter` instead of the old tabs , and after all the changes that i did ,  A `NullPointerException` occurred especially on the line

`int SelectedID = bundle.getInt("selectedID",0);`

note that `getArguments()` return null

here is my code :

the app work fine until l click on the list

```
class WorkoutsFragment extends ListFragment :

@Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

        WorkoutListFragment workoutListFrag = new WorkoutListFragment();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        //WorkoutID.get() to get the real position from database and it works
        bundle.putInt("selectedID", WorkoutID.get(position));
        workoutListFrag.setArguments(bundle);

        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "l Position "+WorkoutID.get(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        mCallback.onSwitchToNextFragment();


            // Set the item as checked to be highlighted when in two-pane layout
           list.setItemChecked(position, true);
    }
```

WorkoutListFragment extends ListFragment

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list, container, false);

    // connect object of listview and listview id on xml
    list = (ListView) v.findViewById(android.R.id.list);


    wla = new WorkoutListAdapter(getActivity());

    // get value that passed from previous page
    //getArguments() returns null, i don't know why
    Bundle bundle = getArguments();
    //here is the line of NullPointerException 
    int SelectedID = bundle.getInt("selectedID",0);


    // call asynctask class to get data from database
    new getWorkoutList().execute();
    }
```

the log

```
01-12 11:29:44.048: E/AndroidRuntime(2404): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-12 11:29:44.048: E/AndroidRuntime(2404): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-12 11:29:44.048: E/AndroidRuntime(2404):     at com.daily.workout.app.WorkoutListFragment.onCreateView(WorkoutListFragment.java:72)
01-12 11:29:44.048: E/AndroidRuntime(2404):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1460)
01-12 11:29:44.048: E/AndroidRuntime(2404):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:911)
01-12 11:29:44.048: E/AndroidRuntime(2404):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1088)
01-12 11:29:44.048: E/AndroidRuntime(2404):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
01-12 11:29:44.048: E/AndroidRuntime(2404):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1444)
01-12 11:29:44.048: E/AndroidRuntime(2404):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:461)
01-12 11:29:44.048: E/AndroidRuntime(2404):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
01-12 11:29:44.048: E/AndroidRuntime(2404):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1012)
01-12 11:29:44.048: E/AndroidRuntime(2404):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:523)
01-12 11:29:44.048: E/AndroidRuntime(2404):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:495)
01-12 11:29:44.048: E/AndroidRuntime(2404):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.dataSetChanged(ViewPager.java:875)
01-12 11:29:44.048: E/AndroidRuntime(2404):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager$PagerObserver.onChanged(ViewPager.java:2690)
01-12 11:29:44.048: E/AndroidRuntime(2404):     at android.database.DataSetObservable.notifyChanged(DataSetObservable.java:37)
01-12 11:29:44.048: E/AndroidRuntime(2404):     at android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(PagerAdapter.java:276)
01-12 11:29:44.048: E/AndroidRuntime(2404):     at com.daily.workout.app.adapter.TabsPagerAdapter$1.onSwitchToNextFragment(TabsPagerAdapter.java:44)
01-12 11:29:44.048: E/AndroidRuntime(2404):     at com.daily.workout.app.WorkoutsFragment.onListItemClick(WorkoutsFragment.java:108)
01-12 11:29:44.048: E/AndroidRuntime(2404):     at android.support.v4.app.ListFragment$2.onItemClick(ListFragment.java:58)
01-12 11:29:44.048: E/AndroidRuntime(2404):     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:298)
01-12 11:29:44.048: E/AndroidRuntime(2404):     at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1100)
01-12 11:29:44.048: E/AndroidRuntime(2404):     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2749)
01-12 11:29:44.048: E/AndroidRuntime(2404):     at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3423)
01-12 11:29:44.048: E/AndroidRuntime(2404):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
01-12 11:29:44.048: E/AndroidRuntime(2404):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-12 11:29:44.048: E/AndroidRuntime(2404):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-12 11:29:44.048: E/AndroidRuntime(2404):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
01-12 11:29:44.048: E/AndroidRuntime(2404):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-12 11:29:44.048: E/AndroidRuntime(2404):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-12 11:29:44.048: E/AndroidRuntime(2404):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
01-12 11:29:44.048: E/AndroidRuntime(2404):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
01-12 11:29:44.048: E/AndroidRuntime(2404):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: where you are adding that fragment to activity.

Comment: it because you are using `TabPagerAdapter` and it is not using `workoutListFrag` instance but another isntance of  `WorkoutListFragment`(which has no arguments setted) ...

Comment: you have set some bundle to that fragment right. then where you are loading object(fragment).

Comment: after you call workoutListFrag.setArguments(bundle); you are not doing anything with the workoutListFrag object. Where do you use it after that call? You need to set it to be the next fragment somewhere.

Comment: If you show the code for onSwitchToNextFragment(), then we can answer how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this  problem , By using only one instance , I made i mistake i put `setArguments` to an instance (`WorkoutListFragment w = new WorkoutListFragment()`) and launch another new instance (`WorkoutListFragment wo = new WorkoutListFragment()`) and this new instace is empty it has no arguments that's why it returned `NullPointerException` .

And another important thing , You have to put bundle arguments directly behind the class that you want to launch(`WorkoutListFragment`) , which mean bundle can survive only between 2 classes successively, And i have 3 , A passed the arguments from the first to the third and it didn't work , the second class was in charge to launch the third one (`WorkoutListFragment`) because i use (`ListFragments ,ViewPager,etc`) , so i set the arguments in the second class.